# codeigniter flipkart product api

Tags: php, codeigniter, flipkart-api

I am trying to get the top deals using the flipkart product feed api in codeigniter.

This is the piece of code that I have written to achieve it.

```
public function getTopDealsFlipkart()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['url'] = 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/'.FK_AFFILIATE_ID.'/category/mens-clothing.json?expiresAt=1510123592000&sig=<urlValidationSignature>&inStock=true';
    $header['Accept'] = 'application/json';
    $header['Fk-Affiliate-Token'] = FK_AFFILIATE_TOKEN;
    $header['Fk-Affiliate-Id'] = FK_AFFILIATE_ID;
    $data['header'] = $header;
    $output = $this->get_response($data);
    return $output;
}

public function get_response($data)
{
    $output = null;
    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $data['url'], [
            'headers' => $data['header']
        ]);
        $output = $response->getBody();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('debug', 'fail to get response ');
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The output that it is returning is null.

I am not able to understand what is 'sig' as the API just defines it as "url validation signature". There is no information further information on the API. What is the URL validation signature and How do I generate the URL validation signature?